# Re-use SonataAdminBundle Fontawesome in my own bundle

Tags: css, symfony, fonts, sonata-admin, assetic

I just installed SonataAdminBundle, I found that SonataAdminBundle already has fontawesome and another css/js assets installed in public folder, my questions is how to re-use those js/css assets in my own Bundle ? here is my code :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
            {% stylesheets
                '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/public/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
                '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/public/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
                '@ApplicationSonataUserBundle/Resources/public/css/signin.css'
                '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/public/vendor/AdminLTE/css/font-awesome.min.css'  
                filter='cssrewrite' 
                filter='yui_css'
            %}
                 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}">
            {% endstylesheets %}

        {% endblock %}
```

but unfortunately all fonts are get 404 state ? is that means we cannot re use all js/css from another vendor bundle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer, here is :
run

```
./app/console assets:install web
```

it will create all bundles assets inside web/ folder, then I change my code to this :

```
{% block stylesheets %}
            {% stylesheets
                'bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
                'bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
                '@ApplicationSonataUserBundle/Resources/public/css/signin.css'
                'bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/AdminLTE/css/font-awesome.min.css'  
                filter='cssrewrite' 
                filter='yui_css'
            %}
                 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}">
            {% endstylesheets %}
```

Then I run

```
./app/console assetic:dump
```

Now everything just work correctly and all fontawesome icons are show